# change display of django model field with choices in serialized fixture

Tags: python, django

I have a model with a model field named `status_type` that uses the `choices` attribute.
When I use the `dumpdata` command from django's `manage.py` with the option `--natural` (django 1.6), then I get `1` or `2` as the serialized representation of that field.

So my question is how can I get the `get_<field>_display` version instead of the raw (database) representation when using `dumpdata --natural`?

**current output**

```
{
  "fields": {
    "name": "todo",
    "type": 1
  },
  "model": "status.status",
  "pk": 1
}
```

**desired output**

```
{
  "fields": {
    "name": "todo",
    "type": "open"
  },
  "model": "status.status",
  "pk": 1
}
```

**context**

```
# status.models.py

class StatusManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, name):
        return self.get(name=name)

    ...


class Status(models.Model):
    """
    Django model representing a processing state.
    """
    objects = StatusManager()

    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    OPEN = 1
    CLOSED = 2
    DEFAULT = OPEN
    TYPES = (
        (OPEN, "open"),
        (CLOSED, "closed"),
    )
    status_type = models.IntegerField(default=DEFAULT, max_length=1, choices=TYPES)

    ...

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Status"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def natural_key(self):
        return [self.name]

    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use models.CharField.

```py
DEFAULT = "open"
TYPES = (
    ("open", "open"),
    ("closed", "closed"),
)
status_type = models.CharField(default=DEFAULT, max_length=20, choices=TYPES)
```